# Javascript - error 'undefined is not a function' raised on previously working code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I call once the document has been loaded that suddenly "broke" and I'm not sure why.  The code is actually working on the production server but no longer works in my development environment?

```js
ImrApp.controller('rfController',
 ["$scope", "$modal", "DataService",
 function rfController($scope, $modal, DataService) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function () {
   getRptTypes();
  });

  // Gets the list of report types...
  var getRptTypes = function () {
   DataService.getRptTypes().then(
    // Success...
    function (results) {
     var data = results.data;

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].active) {
       $scope.rptTypes.push({
        id: data[i].id,
        name: data[i].name
       });
      }
     }
    },
    // Error...
    function (results) {
     // Set the error title and message then display the modal error dialogue...
     $scope.formData.errorTitle = "Get Report Types";
     $scope.formData.errorMsg = "The following error was reported when attempting to retrieve the list of report types;</br></br>" + results.statusText;
     $('#errorDialogue').modal('show');
    }
   )
  };
 }]);
```

When the page loads the line `getRptType();` in `$(document).ready` generates the error `undefined is not an object` in Chrome and `Object expected` in IE11. If I comment out the line the page loads as expected.

I have checked there are no other functions with this name in the project and I even removed all other code (click event handlers, etc) leaving just the code above.

I also tried the following;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $scope.formData.userId = $('#UserId').html();
  //getRptTypes();
  loadRptTypes();
});

var loadRptTypes = function () {
  return;
};
```

but the error is then reported for the line `loadRptTypes();`?

I have verified that jQuery is being loaded along with all of the other scripts required by the application but this doesn't appear to be problem as I can insert a breakpoint on the line in question to confirm that `$(document).ready` is actually called.

Any suggestions to correct this problem would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure that `getRptTypes` gets initialized? From the error it appears that it is not yet set equal to the `function` before the  `ready` event triggers. Due to hoisting `getRptTypes` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter you were right - I had moved `$(document).ready` to the beginning of the code and following your suggestion moved it back to the end and it worked again;

```js
ImrApp.controller('rfController',
 ["$scope", "$modal", "DataService",
 function rfController($scope, $modal, DataService) {
  "use strict";

  // Gets the list of report types...
  var getRptTypes = function () {
   DataService.getRptTypes().then(
    // Success...
    function (results) {
     var data = results.data;

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].active) {
       $scope.rptTypes.push({
        id: data[i].id,
        name: data[i].name
       });
      }
     }
    },
    // Error...
    function (results) {
     // Set the error title and message then display the modal error dialogue...
     $scope.formData.errorTitle = "Get Report Types";
     $scope.formData.errorMsg = "The following error was reported when attempting to retrieve the list of report types;</br></br>" + results.statusText;
     $('#errorDialogue').modal('show');
    }
   )
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {
   getRptTypes();
  });
 }]);
```